# FormGroup model property binding is showing blank on html after reset

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I've been trying to reset the FormGroup on **edit** button of `pushAppointmentData`, here is the code on ts page.

```
pushAppointmentData(loadData: any) {
    this.customersLoadAppointmentModel.registerForm.reset();
    if(loadData.hasOwnProperty("appointmentData")){
      const responseAppointment = loadData.appointmentData;
      this.customersLoadAppointmentModel.ID = responseAppointment?.id;
      this.customersLoadAppointmentModel.loadId = responseAppointment?.loadID;
      this.customersLoadAppointmentModel.xyz = responseAppointment?.loadID;
      this.customersLoadAppointmentModel.customersLoadOriginID = responseAppointment?.customersLoadOriginID;
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    }
    else{
      console.log(loadData?.customersBooksLoadID); //data is shown here everytime  
      this.customersLoadAppointmentModel.loadId = loadData?.customersBooksLoadID;
      this.customersLoadAppointmentModel.customersLoadOriginID = loadData?.id;      
      this.customersLoadAppointmentModel.xyz = loadData?.customersBooksLoadID;
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    }    
  }
```

here is html page.

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="border-0 p-0 text-right"><b>Appt. Required:
            </b> 
         </td>
         <td class="border-0 pl-3 pt-0 pb-0 pt-0">
            Yes
            <a href="" data-toggle="modal"
               data-target="#Appointment"
               (click)="pushAppointmentData(loadData)">
            <i
               class="float-right text-primary mr-2 flaticon2-edit">
            </i></a>
            <!-- Modal-->
            <div class="modal fade" id="Appointment" tabindex="-1"
               role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Appointment"
               aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg"
               role="document">
               <div class="modal-content"
                  [formGroup]="customersLoadAppointmentModel.registerForm">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                     <div class="row pt-3 pb-3 bg-light0">
                        <input type="hidden"
                        formControlName="ID"
                        [(ngModel)]="customersLoadAppointmentModel.ID">
                        <input type="hidden"
                        formControlName="loadId"
                        [(ngModel)]="customersLoadAppointmentModel.loadId"> //data does not fill after pushAppointmentData
                        <input type="hidden"
                        formControlName="xyz"
                        [(ngModel)]="customersLoadAppointmentModel.xyz"> //data does not fill after pushAppointmentData
                        <input type="hidden"
                        formControlName="customersLoadOriginID" [(ngModel)]="customersLoadAppointmentModel.customersLoadOriginID"> //data shows here everytime when pushAppointmentData is clicked.
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- modal -->
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="border-0 p-0 text-right"><b> Pickup Date : </b>
         </td>
         <td class="border-0 pl-3 pt-0 pb-0 pt-0">
            {{loadData.appointmentData?.pickupDate}} 
         </td>
      </tr>          
   </tbody>
</table>
```

this `formControlName="customersLoadOriginID"` gets updated everytime on `pushAppointmentData` but `formControlName="loadID"` and `formControlName="xyz"` does not get updated shows `null` but still gets data on **ts** page here `console.log(loadData?.customersBooksLoadID);` or `responseAppointment?.loadID;`.

Here is first screenshot.
[image]
Here is second screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example in stackblitz?

Comment: @NathanT. it won't be easy to make a minimal example as this is just one part within a `div` which is going through loop and there are other same `div`s which is running along it having same edit and form reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to this problem, used the form reset passing value with property.

```
      this.customersLoadAppointmentModel.registerForm.reset({
        loadId: loadData?.customersBooksLoadID
      });
      this.ref.detectChanges();
```

This stopped the problem altogether getting blank value in the **HTML**.
I was passing just `this.customersLoadAppointmentModel.registerForm.reset();` I guess this is a Form issue which are dynamic in nature.